# Rcaller can't load rJava

Tags: rjava, rcaller

I have this issue on linux when library (rJava) with **rCaller** through **Rscript** in java side:

```
[8/20/14 23:00:52:169 EDT] 000000cc SystemOut     O Error:Loading required package: methods
[8/20/14 23:00:52:169 EDT] 000000cc SystemOut     O Error:Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for     'rJava', details:
[8/20/14 23:00:52:169 EDT] 000000cc SystemOut     O Error:  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
[8/20/14 23:00:52:169 EDT] 000000cc SystemOut     O Error:  error: unable to load shared object   '/opt/rbuilt/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
[8/20/14 23:00:52:169 EDT] 000000cc SystemOut     O Error:  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[8/20/14 23:00:52:169 EDT] 000000cc SystemOut     O Error:Error: package or namespace load failed for ârJavaâ
[8/20/14 23:00:52:169 EDT] 000000cc SystemOut     O Error:Execution halted
[8/20/14 23:00:53:811 EDT] 000000cd SystemOut     O Output:[1] "here 0"
[8/20/14 23:00:54:276 EDT] 000000ce SystemOut     O Error:Loading required package: methods
[8/20/14 23:00:54:276 EDT] 000000ce SystemOut     O Error:Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
[8/20/14 23:00:54:276 EDT] 000000ce SystemOut     O Error:  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
[8/20/14 23:00:54:276 EDT] 000000ce SystemOut     O Error:  error: unable to load shared object '/opt/rbuilt/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
[8/20/14 23:00:54:276 EDT] 000000ce SystemOut     O Error:  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[8/20/14 23:00:54:276 EDT] 000000ce SystemOut     O Error:Error: package or namespace load failed for ârJavaâ
[8/20/14 23:00:54:276 EDT] 000000ce SystemOut     O Error:Execution halted
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Comment: This output does not contain any information about RCaller.